# Squid config different proxy rule

Tags: squid

I want to create a proxy server that when I try to access some urls, the server connect to another server, and other urls will maintain the regular proxy service. Does anyone know how to set this in squild?

Answer (score 0):

specify the domains (I try to access some urls, the server connect to another server, and other urls will maintain the regular proxy service.) in an acl.

if you want to connect to the other server for google requests, define acl as

acl alloweddomains dstdomain google.com google.co.uk

u can simply specify all domains in a text file and load it in acl

```
acl alloweddomains dstdomain "<path>/domains.txt"
```

then use cache_peer option.

```
cache_peer next_server_ip parent 80 0 no-query originserver name=allowserver
cache_peer_access allowserver allow alloweddomains 
cache_peer_access deny all
```

Comment: This is not what I want. The alloweddomains is not what I need. I need something like mycomputer(go to google)-->myproxy(connect to google), and mycomputer(go to yahoo)-->proxy-->another proxy-->yahoo

Answer (score 0):

With your explanation, I realized that :

```
You would need dual or more proxy set on source client.
If this is true ; 

so this is not valid configuration .
```

**The perfect solution for your idea ;**

1. you should set one proxy on your client side
2. other side on your proxy (for example on Squid Proxy server )
3. You could configure tunneling to other proxy servers.